# Connecting to a pool member over SSH w/ a host certificate good for the pool name only

Tags: ssh

I'm using OpenSSH certificates for a pool of hosts. That is to say, in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, there's an entry that looks thus:

```
@cert-authority service.redacted.com ssh-rsa ...
```

...and `service.redacted.com` is a round-robin DNS entry for which each system involved has a host certificate (see the `HostCertificate` entry in `man sshd_config`) signed as valid for `service.redacted.com`.

This works perfectly when wanting to connect to a randomly-selected system from the pool -- but what if someone wants to connect to a single, specific system from the pool, validating its host key as legitimate using the  certificate authority given?

---

One thing I tried was thus:

```
service_name=service.redacted.com
specific_host=1.2.3.4
ssh -v -oHostKeyAlias="$service_name" "$specific_host"
```

...which results in the following:

```
debug1: Host 'service.redacted.com' is known and matches the RSA-CERT host certificate
Certificate invalid: name is not a listed principal
The authenticity of host 'service.redacted.com (1.2.3.4)' can't be established.
```

`service.redacted.com` quite certainly *is* a listed principal in the certificate; `1.2.3.4` is not.

Answer (score 2):

As of current upstream OpenSSH-portable master (https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commits/773dda25e828c4c9a52f7bdce6e1e5924157beab), this is not possible.

The relevant logic is in [the check_host_key() function](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/773dda25e828c4c9a52f7bdce6e1e5924157beab/sshconnect.c#L904), which calls `check_host_cert()` only once -- with the hostname which was originally passed into `ssh_login()` modified only by normalizing all characters to lowercase. That same hostname in passed through `resolve_host()` to get the `addrinfo *` struct used for the actual connection; `resolve_host()` respects a few options (selecting the address family to use), but otherwise does not provide an override mechanism.

---

That said, the change needed is a short one (presently submitted to the upstream mailing list and pending review):

```
From 367fd8323d864daaf486047850f93c2167c66f37 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Charles Duffy <charles@threatgrid.com>
Date: Tue, 17 Feb 2015 09:49:32 -0600
Subject: [PATCH] Allow HostKeyAlias to match a host certificate principal if
 HostName does not

---
 sshconnect.c | 3 ++-
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/sshconnect.c b/sshconnect.c
index df921be..666c3ff 100644
--- a/sshconnect.c
+++ b/sshconnect.c
@@ -902,7 +902,8 @@ check_host_key(char *hostname, struct sockaddr *hostaddr, u_short port,
                debug("Found %s in %s:%lu", want_cert ? "CA key" : "key",
                    host_found->file, host_found->line);
                if (want_cert && !check_host_cert(hostname, host_key))
-                       goto fail;
+                       if (options.host_key_alias == NULL || !check_host_cert(options.host_key_alias, host_key))
+                               goto fail;
                if (options.check_host_ip && ip_status == HOST_NEW) {
                        if (readonly || want_cert)
                                logit("%s host key for IP address "
--
2.0.0
```